# How to run a exe file via unix by passing input parameter

Tags: java, unix

I have created a exe file from jar via converter tools. Jar file was executing fine when I tried to run via unix by passing input parameters eg: `java -jar SSS_Infinite.jar test.in 2`

However after converting to exe I tried to run by passing input parameters via Unix but its not working and simply returns to the next line. I tried the below command in Unix cmd. Is there any other alternative to make it trigger ?

```
SSS_Infinite.exe test1.in 2
```

Comment: As the answer is very likely to depend on it: What tool did you use to "create" an executable from a jar? Clearly it's the documentation of that tool you need to look at, if it's failing to pass on command-line arguments.

Comment: You _do_ know that you simply cannot use the MS-Windows-exclusive ".exe" format on a unixoid system? Instead all you probably need is a two line wrapper around the jar call you successfully tested, so a mini script which you can mark as being executable inside the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you created executable for Windows platform, it will not work on *nix systems.
The simplest option will be to build little script that will accept parameters and pass them to `java -jar`, something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar SSS_Infinite.jar $1 $2
```

where $1 and $2 are script arguments, see explanation [here](http://linux.about.com/od/Bash_Scripting_Solutions/a/How-To-Pass-Arguments-To-A-Bash-Script.htm).

after you create that script and save it as say SSS_Infinite.sh, [change its permissions](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/chmod.html):

```
chmod +x SSS_Infinite.sh
```

Then you'll be able to execute it like that:

```
./SSS_Infinite.sh test1.in 2
```

Comment: Hi Vadchen, jar file is working fine in unix while I pass input parameters to it, my requirement is .exe should be created in lieu of .jar and input parameters to be passed. It should fetch result if I give the following command as such : SSS_infinite.exe test.in 2

Comment: That is what SSS_Infinite.sh does

Comment: Yeah got it thanks, but my requirement states to create .exe, so it's not feasible, am i right?

Comment: @user3380554 .exe files run on **Windows**.  They **cannot** run on any Unix or Linux system.